# php/.net web login bot - out of curiosity

Tags: php, .net, bots

We all know of web bots, spiders and stuff doing automated actions on the web such as logging into accounts such as gmail,hotmail etc' and doing automated actions with legit accounts that saves labor hour or just deliver their spam...

I was wondering how such bot really works  (Im not planning on becoming a spammer , just curious about the implementation of it :-) )

I saw some explanations about how you could be build a .net app that will use a web-browser control and invoke actions on an HTMLdocument but i guess this is not fast and anonymous enough to be the real deal...

can anyone shed some light about this one ?

Answer (score 0):

It works exactly as you describe: There is a webbrowser (component, also known as HTTP client) and it gets commanded. And that's it.

> but i guess this is not fast and anonymous enough to be the real deal...

You guess wrong. It's fast, and anonymity has nothing to do with it.

Comment: No; a real web browser is not fast enough.

Comment: Define "real web browser" please. I find your statement too broad to be true.

Comment: Who is seriously calling IE a real browser^^